# Can I disregard the sticker on my sparewheel?

Tags: tires, wheels, spare-tire

This week I got a flat tire. I replaced the tire with my spare one. Since I own a Volkswagen the spare is a full size tire. The spare have a sticker on it that say don't go over 80km/h (50miles/h). However, the tire spec are 195/65r15 H same dimension spec as factory wheel setting. According to [this table](http://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=35), the speed rating of the tire is 210km/h (130miles/h) so the tire is way more capable than the 80km/h limit posted on the sticker.

Is there any reason why this sticker is there? If so can you explain please?

Comment: Interesting question. I want to know the answer to this as well.

Answer (score 4):

TireRack indicates that there may be [other differences at play.](http://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=141)

> Full-Size Temporary Spares
>
> Full-size temporary spare tires and wheels match the vehicle's original tire dimensions, but typically feature lighter-weight construction and a shallower tread depth to reduce vehicle weight to improve fuel economy and make the spare easier to install. While most of today's vehicles are originally equipped with alloy wheels, full-size temporary spares are typically mounted on steel wheels and should be used only as spares.

Even if the spare tire is the exact same size as the tire it will be replacing it can still have a difference of tread depth. [This might impact an all-whee-drive vehicle, depending on manfuacturer.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/will-different-tread-depths-hurt-my-4-wheel-drive)

When in doubt the manufacturer is not usually out to get you. There's likely some safety consideration for the speed limit. Volkswagen offers a free phone and live chat system, you can try [asking them directly](http://www.vw.com/contact/).

Comment: thank you, as for the steal part, the car come on them from base. I will try to have a chat with them today and come back with their answer.